# modal doesn't show up but grey background appears on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamically created table and on click of view button present in every row it shows up a grey screen but the model doesn't open ..I tried a lot but not understanding where the problem is involved.I took help of https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html his code as reference.

***please help me...***

*m_manage.html---Here I declared modal and included the page*

---

```
<div class="panel-body">
 <table class="table table-hover" id="table">                      
   <tbody>
      {% include 'm_manage/partial_m_manage.html' %}
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>              
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-leave">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
 </div>
</div>
```

*partial_m_manage.html : It contains the the columns in table*

---

```
{% for  pl in pending_leaves %}
<tr> 
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm view" data-url="{% url 'm_manage:leave_view' pl.id %}" data-target="#{{pl.id}}_3"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" style="color:black"></i></button>                                        
   </td>                                   
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

js----call to on click of button

```
    $("#table").on('click', '.view', function (e) {
    var btn = $(this);
    console.log(btn);
    var url= btn.attr("data-url");
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
      // url: '/m_manage/leave_view/', 
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',

      beforeSend: function () {
       $("#modal-leave").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log('You Did it!!!!');
        $("#modal-leave .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  });
```

*views.py--*

---

```
def leave_view(request,pk):
  Leave = get_object_or_404(leave, pk=pk);
  data=dict()
  if request.method == 'POST':
     data['html_form']= render_to_string('m_manage/view_modal.html',{'Leave':Leave}, request=request)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

view_modal.html---I am rendering a new page ie modal

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'm_manage:leave_view' Leave.id %}" class="js-leave-view-form">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Do you want to accept {{Leave.id}} leave</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"> 
  <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create book</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

But the black screen appears and all values prints successfully in the console but modal popup doesn't appear...

***Please help me... :(***

Comment: i have not gone through all the code you have given but may be you are missing {% endfor%} in partial_m_manage.html

Comment: sorry,its present in my code but I didnt put here

Comment: did you complete all steps in simpleisbetterthancomplex coz it looks like long road

Comment: I implemented the delete book code of his page to my view  leaves as the functionality is same.I even downloaded his code and its running fine but i dont understand why my popup is not appearing

Comment: have you done inspect element to see if the DOM has been updated or not? if it has been try adjusting the z-index.I had faced a similar issue once

Comment: In my console i got    Element does not exist in DOM!  in jquery.news.ticker ..is it causing problem?I have that error from the beginning even before introducing modals

Comment: is it a design issue related to css or my code?

Comment: You are returning JsonResponse(data) from view to that ajax request and in javascript you are replacing HTML so that might be the issue. please check.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You should include "bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: "<div class="modal fade" id="modal-leave">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
 </div>
</div>" - here you should have one more ending div like this- </div> if i am not mistaken or you forgot that to add here in your question.....

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It turned out to be because the button which triggered the modal was before the partial which was being rendered. I just switched those two things around in the html i.e.

```
<%= render 'some_modal' %>
<%= link_to 'Click here' %>
```

not

```
<%= link_to 'Click here' %>
<%= render 'some_modal' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (besides the modal problem, my entire website looked 'wrong'), and it turns out that bower downloaded the wrong Bootstrap version.

My `bower.json` specifies `"bootstrap": "3.3.0"`, but `bower install` downloads version 5.2.3, breaking my site.
Adding a caret inside my bower.json fixed the issue for me: `"bootstrap": "^3.3.0",`

I think the problem is that there might be other dependencies that bower tries to resolve, and then automatically pulls the latest version, ignoring your version specification. The caret makes sure that whatever version bower pulls, is backwards compatible.